# why am i getting undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to delete something posted by a user. But it's not working the way it normally does despite the fact that I'm mirroring a setup I've used in other apps.

My html:

```
 <div class="section-wrap">
    <% @colors.each do |color| %>
        <div class="swatch">
        <div class="colorblock" style="background-color: <%= color.backgroundcolor %>">
        </div>
        <h2>PANTONE<sup>2</sup></h2>
        <p><%= color.name %></p>
      </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <% if current_user %>
                <%= link_to 'Delete', @color, method: :delete %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My controller action:

```
def destroy
   @color.destroy
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

My routes.rb (in which I should not have to specify the delete route):

```
resources :colors
delete 'colors', to: 'colors#destroy'
```

And then `rake routes` gives the route I'd expect:

```
DELETE /colors/:id(.:format)        colors#destroy
```

But I get `undefined method 'destroy' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Try to see if color object is present or nil. Form the error message I can see that color object is nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've loaded `@color`, and instance variables are automatically initialized to `nil` (in contrast with local variables, which raise an exception if you use them without assigning them). Hence, Ruby complains that `destroy` is undefined on `nil`. Load `@color` first:

```
@color = Color.find(params[:id])
```

If you're using `Color.find_by_id` somewhere else in your controller (eg. a `before_action`), perhaps the ID just doesn't correspond to an existing Color. Unlike `find`, `find_by_id` will return `nil` when the record is missing.

Comment: Well `Color.find` would never return nil, it would raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. So since he apparently isn't seeing that then I'm guessing, like you said, just is missing that line completely.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:

```
#View
<% @colors.each do |color| %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', color, method: :delete %> #-> @color doesn't exist
<% end %>

#Controller
def destroy
  @color = Color.find params[:id]
  @color.destroy
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

The above should work for you.